# Model does not contain a definition error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am having an issue in my project and wonder if some can pinpoint me to where i may have gone wrong. so basically in my project i have got an ActionResult method like so:

```
public ActionResult PartNumberManufacturer(string id)
{
  var partNumber = _Context.PartNumberTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.partNumberId == id);
  return PartialView("PartNumberView",    partNumber);
}
```

Then this is my view

```
@if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PartNumberManufacturer))
{
  @if (Model.PartNumberManufacturer == "Fr")
  {
    <div>
      <p> This product is developed in france </p>
      @if (@Model.PartNumberManufacturer == "Ger")
      {
        <p> This Product is developed in Germany </p>
      }
```

well the above code works fine. but the thing is that if you look back into my ActionResult controller method , i am using :

```
var partNumber = Context.PartNumberTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.partNumberId == id);
```

FirstOrDefault of-course will only return the first found part number in the database. 
This isnot what i am looking for i don't want it only to return the first found record , i want it to return all the records that match by the search query in the database. So in order to do and after a few research online i found that i had to return the results into a list and this made me amend my ActionResult method to like this:

```
public ActionResult PartNumberManufacturer(string id)
{
  var _methodOfRepair = Context.PartNumberTable.Where(x => x.PartNumberId == id); // changed thisline
  return PartialView("PartNumberView",    partNumber);
}
```

so yeah i get the error message saying that:

> {"'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' does not contain a
>   definition for 'PartNumberManufacturer'"}

i made those changes. what am i doing wrong here? or is there a different approach i can be recommended to in order to achieve this?

thank you for your time.

Comment: It the first example, your model was a single object, but in the second example its a collection of objects (and a collection does not contain a property named `PartNumberManufacturer` (your need to iterate your collection an access each object in the collection)

Comment: You have to either change your view model to **List<Model>** or iterate through each one to find he one you want in your controller

Comment: Hi , thank you for responding .... after doing what you said i am no longer getting that error.. but i have another issue that occurring in my project , i don't know where i am going wrong.. in my view i am using for each loop to loop through my model but for some reason it only returns the results of the the first matched record in the database and but doesn't return the other results .. would have any idea to why this is?

Answer (score 0):

First recommendation, read about [implementing the repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Second, if you are sending a collection of objects to your `View` then your View need to be expecting that data type. Change the `Model` data type that your View is expecting.

Inside your View, you should iterate over every element and render it.

Comment: @user5203902 did this help? Please, select this as an answer if it did. Otherwise, keep the post updated so we can help.